# Unable to access documentation in visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

The documentation system in my VS2008 installation seems to have become corrupted. Neither the Help-Contents window not the Help-Index window display anything apart from the Filter popdown (which seems to be empty) - and if I try to use this popdown I get a the error message

"The selected filter contains an error that prevents it from being applied"

There must be some corrupted index somewhere - any suggestions for a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

I found [this solution](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.vsnet.documentation/browse_thread/thread/2e708bc8f93f6697) for the error message you describe on microsoft.public.vsnet.documentation:

> ...My error was caused by corrupt help
> file  nslist.hxl in
> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft Help. I guess
> it was my hard disk  problem. My fix
> was to overwrite nslist.hxl by a good
> copy from another  machine.

**EDIT**

You can try a Repair installation on Visual Studio.

Comment: I had already found that suggestion and tried it, but it doesn't seem to resolve the problem
Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

There's a Microsoft Connect issue describing a similar problem with VS2005 and is related to the user having previous beta/CTP versions installed. In the 2nd post of the thread he mentions registry entries that he deleted to get it to work: [MSDN/Help corrupt or missing](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=107582).

> I had a look in the
>   registry under
>   current_user\software\microsoft\msdn
>   and there was stuff there for 7.0 &
>   QTR. I deleted these then selected
>   Product Documentation from the VS05
>   start menu and it's now all working.

Comment: I don't seem have any conflicting versions in the registry so I don't think that's the problem
Thanks for the suggestion though!